# Bluetooth device not found after restart on Fedora

Tags: fedora, bluetooth

I just restarted bluetooth but instead of using `systemctl restart` I've used `systemctl stop` and then `systemctl start`, the status look like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-10-16 09:14:16 CEST; 1min 27s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 26199 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─26199 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

paź 16 09:14:16 jcubic systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
paź 16 09:14:16 jcubic bluetoothd[26199]: Bluetooth daemon 5.49
paź 16 09:14:16 jcubic systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
paź 16 09:14:16 jcubic bluetoothd[26199]: Starting SDP server
paź 16 09:14:16 jcubic bluetoothd[26199]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

but config panel give me error that no adapter found and `hciconfig` give no results.

I've tried to install `bluez-hid2hci` (I've read somewhere about this) and after no effect I've uninstalled it.

I've restarted the machine but then I don't get bluetooth icon in task bar and I've got this in terminal:

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
$ dmesg | grep blue
[    8.591069] SELinux:  Class bluetooth_socket not defined in policy.
```

After some digging I've notice that bluetooth kernel module was not loaded so I've used:

```
# modeprobe bluetooth
# systemctl restart bluetooth
# cd /etc/modules-load.d
# echo "bluetooth" >> bluetooth.conf
```

And now I have the same as in the beginning systemctl status show active but no icon after reboot and this output:

```
# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

the output of dmesg:

```
# dmesg | grep -i blue
[    8.798170] SELinux:  Class bluetooth_socket not defined in policy.
[   16.146091] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.146132] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.146135] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.146136] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.146141] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  318.675520] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  318.675524] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  318.675531] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialize
```

How can I enable bluetooth on Fedora or any other Linux distro that have similar setup? I have Dell Laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this question [Bluetooth not working (No Adapters Available) in fedora-22(KDE)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247381/bluetooth-not-working-no-adapters-available-in-fedora-22kde) someone suggested Cold boot (shutdown and start again) and then check the logs, didn't thought that this will be any different then reboot but it make my bluetooth work again.

Comment: A cold restart solved my problem on Fedora 33... crazy

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. Thanks a lot!

Now I have even more questions..why did it stop working suddenly, and why it worked with a cold restart?

Comment: @aks Sorry, I have no idea.